# Type 'Area<X>' is not assignable to type 'String' using @types/d3

Tags: typescript, d3.js, definitelytyped

I have an instance method on a typescript class...

```
createArea = d3.area<Point>().x((d) => d.x).y0((d) => d.max).y1((d) => d.y);
```

This works but it is being interpreted as an instance field, so I attempted to add a typed lambda...

```
createArea = (points:Point[]):String => d3.area<Point>().x((d) => d.x).y0((d) => d.max).y1((d) => d.y);
```

This does not work

> Type 'Area' is not assignable to type 'String'.

Is this an issue with the type definition (@types/d3) ?

```
export function area<Datum>(): Area<Datum>;
```

The Area() method *definately* returns a string..

```
if (buffer) return output = null, buffer + "" || null;
```

This is my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "^5.5.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/d3": "^5.0.0",
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `d3.area()` returns not `String`, but `Area` abject, which, in turn, is a function accepting array of datums (in your case, a `Point[]`) and returning `String`. This could be checked by the following line:

```
const tmp = d3.area()([]); // tmp is of type string | null
```

So, if you do really need the string instead of `Area` object, you function must look as such (added some formatting for readability):

```
const createArea = (points:Point[]):String => d3.area<Point>()
                                                .x((d) => d.x)
                                                .y0((d) => d.max)
                                                .y1((d) => d.y)
                                                (points)!;
```

The misunderstanding must be based on the fact that the `d3-area` module returns not the function that was named `area` inside it, but the anonymous function which returns the first one. This is the object-oriented approach in JavaScript: the class is just a function returning the instance (which in this case is the `area` function you're referring to).